# how to join two tables and then update in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have two tables having one column common as they are connected with each other.
I want to update the data in both tables at once

```
function profile_update($pre,$data)
                {
                    $this->db->select('*');
                    $this->db->from('users');
                    $this->db->where(array('users.pre' => "$pre"));
                    $this->db->join('user_data', 'user_data.pre = users.pre');
                    $this->db->set($data);
                    $this->db->update('users');

                }
```

> *Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'address' in 'field list'

This is the error I am getting as it is updating only one table seems like Join is not working.*

Comment: Use selects for selecting data, and updates for updating. Here, you're updating, so no need for any selects.

Comment: The last two lines are the only ones being used in this instance. So you are setting $data as an array with fields/values and only updating the 'users' table. Sounds like you have a field called address that isn't in the users table. What fields are you trying to update in both tables? Sounds like you are thinking about this the wrong way.